# Community Questions

Tags: feature-request, list-questions

I am requesting that questions be allowed to be asked in manner of mass answer. Please visit either of these links to understand my question.

[[Hidden features of Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395/hidden-features-of-windows-batch-files) ]

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16820580/batch-for-command-features?noredirect=1#comment24250587_16820580 ]

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question is quite unclear. What is it you're asking?

Comment: i am asking if we can ask questions that anyone can reference to instead of everyone asking individual questions, please follow the links @AlEverett

Comment: I followed the links. It's not self-evident what it is you're after.

Comment: @cmd, I think what you're requesting is that the community allow what are sometimes called "list" or "poll" questions, where each answer lists one thing, and the votes theoretically rank their popularity, yes?  That's been discussed in questions like [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52916/how-to-do-polling-on-stackoverflow-to-share-experiences-of-developers/52922#52922).

Comment: See: [Feature Request: “Ask For List”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127610/feature-request-ask-for-list) and [Should 'hidden features of X' be removed/closed/locked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56669/should-hidden-features-of-x-be-removed-closed-locked)

Comment: Note the big 'ol "Locked" message below the first question; those sorts of broad questions generally aren't allowed (anymore), the old ones have been kept simply because they *already* have value.

Comment: Yes and all of your basis for your answers are coming from the current rules. That's why im asking if we can revise this. I believe that it would tremendously help the communtiy. My current question that i posted of this type has only been disapproved because of the current rules. Mine is certaintly not the only question of this type. I strongly suggest that we counter this to be permitted.

Comment: @cmd These rules aren't just arbitrarily created.  They were the result of quite a lot of discussion, debate, experimentation, etc.  You should first read through the (many) existing meta questions on this topic to understand why these guidelines were put in place to begin with, and the explanations given to the users who, like you, have not agreed with it over the years.  Finally, this meta question is of very low quality.  You question should make it very clear what you're asking about, what your proposal is (if you have one), why you feel it would be better (with detailed support), etc.

Answer (score 4):

To quote Ken White in the comments of your question:

> Please read the block at the bottom of the post you linked, where it says that the post is only being kept for historical reasons but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site. Then please read the faq and about pages to see what sorts of questions are proper to ask here. :-) –

Then read the bottom of the first question you linked to, paying careful attention to the bold text:

> This question exists because it has historical significance, but **it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site**, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq).

As everything says this is no longer considered a good on-topic question, hence yours was closed.

To quote from the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here...